# Fetch information from realtime database in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, mobile

[image]
I would like to know how I can get the value of the post which is *4* from the realtime database in flutter. I tried this and it is not working.

```
  Future<Query> querystats() async {
      var user = await firebaseauth.currentUser();
      _userid = user.uid;
      return FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("stats").child("another");
    }

 querystats().then((query) {
      query.once().then((snapshot) async {
        var snapshot = await query.once();
        var result = snapshot.value.values as Iterable;
        for (var item in result) {
          print(item['posts']);
        }
```

][2]][2]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N84c.png)

Comment: Why it’s not working? What’s the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to read the value of a single property, you don't need the loop and `Iterable`.

It can be something like:

```
var user = await firebaseauth.currentUser();
_userid = user.uid;
var query = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("stats/another/posts");
var snapshot = await query.once()
var result = snapshot.value;
print(result);
```

The changes I made:

- You can pass an entire path into `child`, which saves some characters.
- Use `await` on the call to `once()`, so that you don't need a `then` block.
- Remove the loop, since the snapshot now contains the exact value you're looking for.

I didn't run the code, but this should be pretty close.

Comment: The above solution worked excellently. Thankyou. Now what i am trying to do is to make it dynamic. So when the userid changes the value changes but i am unable to. `
    `var posts_query =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("stats/" + user.uid.toString() +  "/posts");
    var posts_snapshot = await posts_query.once();
    var posts_string = posts_snapshot.value;
    _posts = posts_string;
    print("posts" + _posts);` @Frank van Puffelen

Comment: for some reason i cannot concatenate in the database reference. When i place the value directly into the reference without any concatenation. it works. Otherwise it doesnt

Comment: That seems unexpected, but I must admit I never concatenate strings like that in Flutter. In this specific case, I'd prefer `FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("stats").child(user.uid).child("posts")`